# Binding user control from parent datacontex WPF

Tags: wpf, controls, model-binding

Im trying to bind/link a datagrid from my main window
MainForm:

```
<dx:DXWindow
x:Class="LicenceManagerWPF.Forms.frmCustomerLicense"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="Office2016"  
xmlns:ctr="clr-namespace:LicenceManagerWPF.Controls"
Title="CustomerLicence" Height="800" Width="1000" 
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Loaded="DXWindow_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="200" Height="200*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="200*"/>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="25" Height="25"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel  x:Name="Stack_Top" Orientation="Horizontal"  Grid.Row="0" >
        <dx:SimpleButton x:Name="btnRefresh" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BtnSmall}" ToolTip="Refresh Licenses" Glyph="{dx:DXImage Image=Refresh_32x32.png}" Content="Resfresh" />
        <dx:SimpleButton x:Name="btndNew" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BtnSmall}"  ToolTip="New License" Glyph="{dx:DXImage Image=New_32x32.png}" Content="New Customer"  />
        <dx:SimpleButton x:Name="btnDelete" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BtnSmall}"  ToolTip="Delete Licence" Content="Delete" Glyph="{dx:DXImage Image=Cancel_32x32.png}"/>
        <dx:SimpleButton x:Name="btnEdit" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BtnSmall}" ToolTip="Edit Customer" Glyph="{dx:DXImage Image=EditContact_32x32.png}" />
        <TextBlock Text="Customer: " FontSize="20" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Customer.Name}" FontSize="20"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <ctr:Licences TblLicenses ="{Binding LicensesTable}"  Grid.Row="1">
    </ctr:Licences>
    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>            
        <ctr:LicenseDetail x:Name="ct_LicenseDetail" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <ctr:LicenceLog x:Name="ct_LicenseLog" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I created this control:

```
      <UserControl x:Class="LicenceManagerWPF.Controls.Licences"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid" 
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="500"
         x:Name="ctrl_Licenses">
<Grid>        
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="70" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Licence List" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="22" Margin="10" TextAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <dxg:GridControl x:Name="grdLicences" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TblLicenses,ElementName=ctrl_Licenses}"  Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

I asaigned the control in one row of the grid in the main window.
The main window is linked(data context) to one class that has this methods

```
 private DataTable GetLicensesTable()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn []{
            new DataColumn("SerialNumber",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Product",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Status",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("ActivationMode",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("MaxComputers", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("NumActive",typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("Description",typeof(string))
        });
        _Licenses.ForEach((x) => {
            var rw = dt.NewRow();
            rw["SerialNumber"] = x.SerialNumber;
            rw["Product"] = x.Product.Name;
            rw["Status"] = x.Status;
            rw["ActivationMode"] = Enum.GetName(typeof(ActivationModeEnum), x.ActivationMode);   //x.ActivationMode;
            rw["MaxComputers"] = x.MaxComputers;
            rw["NumActive"] = Activated(x.Product.ProductId);
            rw["Description"] = x.Description;
            dt.Rows.Add(rw);
        });
        return dt;
    }        

    public DataTable LicensesTable{
        get { return GetLicensesTable(); }
   }
```

what i want is to display the table in the grid that is in the usercontrol.
It is posible?

I tryed this in the code behind my main window:

```
private void DXWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_CustomerLicense != null)
        {
            this.DataContext = _CustomerLicense;
            this.ct_LicensesList.grdLicences.ItemsSource = _CustomerLicense.LicensesTable();
        }
        else
        {
            this.DataContext = _CustomerLicense.LicensesTable();
        }
    }
```

it says that tblLicenses is not reconized or not accesible.

Runnin the part of the code behin it works but i think its incorrect the way that im using the control.

Regards

Comment: It was pretty hard to understand what you want to do. You need attached or dependency property in your UC, (for you the 2nd one will be better). When you create it, you can assign it to you'r "tblLicences", and then bind what you want to it. 

And the second thing: Why do you wrote: 
  else
        {
            this.DataContext = _CustomerLicense.LicensesTable();
        } ?? 
Why do you assing something to DataContext if it's null?

Comment: I wanted to assaing an empty object to the datacontext to work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<dxg:GridControl x:Name="grdLicences" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.LicensesTable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

It should work provided that the `DataContext` of the window has a `LicensesTable` property.

Comment: Hi mm8, thanks fro the help,it works using the relativeresource. im working in doing something like this:
I have the grid (now shows the licenses )  when you select a license it shows the detail of the license in another control.
My main windows has the grid and 2 small controls for the details of the license selected.
I will keep working on it,  thanks for your help